# regex - What is the complexity of this regular expression for primes detect?

Tags: ruby, regex, big-o, time-complexity, primes

This line of ruby code detects prime numbers (awesome!).

```
("1" * n) !~ /^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/   # where n is a positive integer
```

The detail is explained in this blog post http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/

I'm curious about it's performance in the manner of BIG-O notation. Anyone help?

Comment: The blog comments talk about performance already and how it begins to suffer terribly at even slightly large numbers. This comment seems apt: `"So a 32 bit number 2147483648 would take up half a gig of memory"`

Comment: As far as it is a really clever use of regular expressions, it is, complexity-wise, incredibly worse than using just the most trivial algorithms for prime numbers!

Comment: anyway, I would like to see the FSM generated by that regex. It seems to me that it would be O(N) where N is the magnitude of the number, while other algorithms are usually O(sqrt(N)) IIRC. Not to mention it is O(N) space-wise too, which makes it not viable for big Ns. (Obviously it's O(N) space-wise **in ruby**, because one could implement a Range in C++ that would be matchable to the regex, but wouldn't occupy N bytes '1') :-D

Comment: This doesn't work when n=1, which is a prime number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From empirical data it appears to be **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

I ran the Ruby code on every 100th of the first 10000 primes. Here are the results:

[image: Graph showing time taken to check if a number is prime.]

The blue dots are the recorded times and the orange line is `y = 2.9e-9 * x^2`. The line fits the data perfectly, indicating that the complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

This is to be expected since the regular expression checks all possible divisors to see if any of them occurs a whole number of times in the string.

Comment: couldn't the slowdown be coming from the memory allocation and not from the regex application?

Comment: I ran it again and the memory usage was only around 4MB.